# FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google Cloud Platform service has been suspended. Please contact support to restore service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm just starting on GCP, i want to create a project but it just fails with generic error
[image]

cloud shell at least give some useless info to contact support:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google Cloud Platform service has been suspended. Please contact support to restore service.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: Google Cloud Platform service has been suspended. Please contact
      support to restore service.
    type: SERVICE
```

Probably this was caused by some billing issue in the past (3+years ?), actually i have just 1 active billing account..

But i have no way to contact the support as i have no project to select... anyone know how to fix this loophole?

Comment: After contacting the support, getting pingponged by the "Quota increase team" and support, 4 months, and various meet call with support agent that want to see the error with screenshare, they fixed my issue. So never give up and reply to EVERY mail they send you also if it looks like an automated mail :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Stack Overflow community can do nothing in such cases**.

**To solve your issue** you should reach out to [Billing and Payments Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/) team and they can definitely investigate your issue related to suspension and would be able to advise you way forward.

In addition, have a look at the documentation [Project suspension guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines) section [Google Cloud project suspension](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines#gcp_project_suspension)

> Google Cloud projects may be suspended due to violations of the GCP
> ToS, including the Google Cloud Acceptable Use Policy (GCP AUP). When
> activities that violate the Google Cloud AUP or ToS are detected in a
> project, the project owner has an obligation to fix the violation
> immediately. If the violation is not fixed, Google may take action to
> suspend the project. It is important that Google Cloud developers
> check the project owner email account regularly. If Google suspends a
> Google Cloud project then all the associated Google Cloud workloads
> will be suspended as well. The owner of a suspended project will
> receive a notification email from google-cloud-compliance@google.com
> with resources to appeal.

also, at the section [Billing account suspension](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines#billing_account_suspension):

> Google Cloud billing accounts may be suspended due to violations of
> Google Cloud ToS or for suspected fraud. If a billing account is
> suspended then all Google Cloud resources attached to that billing
> account are suspended as well.